# Can help me to make Auto Generate ID?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, primary-key

I have form want to Auto Generate that ID from Primary Key
so that code like that

```
private void setidphoto()
{
   DataTable dt = con.FillTable("SELECT IDPhoto FROM Produksi ORDER BY IDPhoto DESC");
      if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
      {
         txtIdPhoto.Text = "PH001";
      }
      else {
         string temp = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
         int IDplus= int.Parse(temp.Substring(2)) + 1;
         string NewID = String.Format("PH{0:000}", IDPlus);
         txtIdPhoto.Text = NewID;
      }
}
```

The Error is `con.FillTable` cant compile or run it, can you help me

Comment: Add the code for FillTable method as well.

Comment: @Bayeni : how sir ? can you help to write to me ?

Comment: What is `con.FillTable` ?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171794/retrieve-data-from-a-sql-server-database-in-c-sharp

Comment: @MairajAhmad : cant filltable like that sir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("yourconnectionstringhere");
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT IDPhoto FROM Produksi ORDER BY IDPhoto DESC", con);
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
add.SelectCommand = com;
adp.Fill(dt);
```