# Method with return type as object

Tags: c#, oop

I tried this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172067/7482204) method but I can't seem to figure out how I will call the method with the class name as a return type.

Item.cs:

```
class Item
{
    public Item GetItem(string parameter) 
    {
        Item itemObj = new Item();

        string query = "select * from items where model = @model";
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection()) 
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,connection)) 
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model",parameter);
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
                    {
                        while (reader.Read()) 
                        {
                            itemObj.Id = int.Parse(reader["id"].ToString());
                            itemObj.Model = reader["model"].ToString();
                            itemObj.Brand = reader["brand"].ToString();
                            itemObj.CategoryId = int.Parse(reader["category_id"].ToString());
                            itemObj.SubCategoryId = int.Parse(reader["sub_category_id"].ToString());
                            itemObj.HasSerialNumber = (int.Parse(reader["serialized"].ToString()) == 1 ? true : false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
        }
        //Console.WriteLine("End"+itemObj.Model);
        return itemObj;
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to access the method GetItem

```
Item itemObj = GetItem("params");
```

but I'm having an error "then name GetItem does not exist on current context"

Comment: `throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);` is a very bad idea. You won't know what actually happened there

Comment: Also, `(int.Parse(reader["serialized"].ToString()) == 1 ? true : false);` could simply be: `reader["serialized"].ToString() == "1";`

Answer (score 4):

change GetItem to be static, then you should be able to calls it as

```
Item item = Item.GetItem("params")
```

On a related note, according to the Single Responsibility Principal (SRP) the class Item should not be responsible for it's persistence. So you'd be better off separating it into 2 classes, Item and ItemsRepository or similar. Then you should be able to create an instance of the repository and call GetItem on that instance (without `static`)

```
class ItemsRepository
{
    public Item GetItem(string params)
    {
         ....
    }
}


 var repo = new ItemsRepo();
 var item = repo.GetItem("params");
```

Comment: I created another class as you suggested and put the GetItem method on ItemCreator and created an instance     ItemCreator itemCreatorObj =  GetItem(params) but it doesn't work, the getItem still needs to be static..then create an Object of    Item itemObj = ItemCreator.GetItem(), and the ItemCreator extends Item class so that I can access the Item properties.

Answer (score 2):

`GetItem` is an instance method which means you need to already have an item instance available and then call `yourItem.GetItem("params")` on it. It sounds like you just want to set `GetItem` to be a static method so you can access it outside of any item instance like this: `Item yourItem = Item.GetItem("params")`. In order to do that, change `public Item GetItem(string parameter)` to `public static Item GetItem(string parameter)`. It's definitely worth rethinking having your data access and mapping logic bundled directly into your item model, but that's a different question that you didn't ask.

Comment: " It's definitely worth rethinking having your data access and mapping logic bundled directly into your item model, but that's a different question that you didn't ask." . as Zdravko Danev said, I must have 2 classes for, one for Item properties and one for the logic.