# how to export sql server table to MS- acess using ssis script task dynamically?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, script-task

I'm trying to load data from SQL server to ms-access using script task in SSIS.
I can do the same only when I know the structure of the table in ms-access, but I don't know the structure in Microsoft Access (means dynamically).

How to achieve this?

Comment: SSIS requires static definitions of data. If the DDL of your tables/objects are forever changing this implies a fundamental problem with your design. SSIS will not be a helpful tool if you can't keep the design of your database static.

Comment: since you are using a script task, I think you should search on this topic without mentioning SSIS, you need to search how to [read data from SQL Server using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171794/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-sql-server-database-in-c) and [Write data into Access using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941284/how-to-insert-a-record-into-a-access-table-using-oledb) then implement this logic inside the Script Task